# Where can I download sample security log file archives?

Tags: siem, log-analysis

I am volunteering to teach some folks to learn Splunk to analyze logs by using SIEM. Therefore I will need some public log file archives such as auditd, secure.log, firewall, webapp logs, which I can use to upload to Splunk instance and write some queries on it.

Do you have any place you know I can download those kind of log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hosting the Splunk instance yourself, you can install the [Splunk Add-on for Unix and Linux](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/833/) and grab those logs from your Splunk server. You can run a bare-bones Splunk install well below the specs listed on their website.

Here are some [syslogs](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/net.mit.edu/scratch/var/log/) from an MIT server (not all are viewable), but I will post a better repository if I am able to find one.

Comment: Thanks for that. The link you provided has some data such as apache log files, which helped me as a start.

Comment: @Blacklion This weekend I have some free time and I can probably post some logs from one of my homelab servers